# Java Apache Beam - save file "LOCALY" by using DataflowRunner

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

```
Can send the java code but currently, it's not necessary.
```

I have an issue as when I run the job as (DirectRunner - using Google VM Instance) it is working fine, as it saves information to the local file and carries on...

The problem appears when trying to use (DataflowRunner), and the error which I receive:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileExtension: XXXX.csv
.....
.....
XXXX.csv could not be delete.
```

It could be deleted as it not even created.

Problem - how to write the file locally when running through **DataflowRunner**??

**P.S.** Using Apache Beam

Pipeline (part of the code) - [Reading from BigQuery and store data to Google storage (Special Character issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170235/reading-from-bigquery-and-store-data-to-google-storage-special-character-issue)

Comment: The question is unclear. From the question it looks like something attempts to delete the file that doesn't exist. It's unclear what part of the code does it, can you share a stack trace for this error? And in a comment you're also saying that the file is available in GCS, so does it mean that the pipeline crashes only some time? Or does it always work but produces a corrupt file and an error in the log?

Comment: Please also share the pipeline code if you can, it is helpful to see how you write to the output in your code

Comment: @Anton Question is regarding DataflowRunner and how to save the file locally if it runs in the dataflow.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by saving it locally. As Ruoyun mentioned, you have to upload the files to GCS or some other storage service when using Dataflow. The pipeline is executed by Dataflow in parallel, on a potentially huge fleet of workers. If they were saving results locally you would have to go and collect the results from each worker's file system. Which is infeasible out of the box, considering, for example, that the workers are ephemeral. The most straightforward solution in this case is to upload the results somewhere (GCS, database, etc). Each worker can do this independently.

Comment: So in this case the easiest path to get the files to your local machine - run the pipeline that uploads the results to GCS and then download the files to your local machine (this can probably be automated as well).

Comment: @Anton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170235/reading-from-bigquery-and-store-data-to-google-storage-special-character-issue

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK when it is ran as a dataflow instance, you have to write file to GCS service (aka storage bucket) rather than local disk.

Did you try that already? to create storage bucket: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets

Comment: Yes, sorry have not mentioned this. The issue is that if I save the file to google storage it corrupt Japanese characters.

Comment: I see. In that case I don't have a good answer right away.  Need to look further.    One thing worth trying tough is, maybe we can serialize whatever text data, then write them as byte strings to file.  And later on serialize it back to JP chars.