# Can Google Data flow use existent VM and not temporary created ones?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Same as title, can Dataflow use not temporary created VM instances but the one already made?

Comment: Howdy and welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the bigger thinking behind the question (this may help us answer it).  What is your thinking or reason for wanting already existing compute resources to exist to run Dataflow jobs?

Comment: Have this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156510/java-apache-beam-save-file-localy-by-using-dataflowrunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking the OP about the reason for the request which was then pointed to as a reply, I am going to offer the following as potential answer:

The power behind Dataflow is to achieve a high degree of parallelism when processing data pipelines.  The back-story of the original request was that "something" was working when run as a local runner but not working as desired when using Dataflow as a runner.  This then appears to have resulted in the OP thinking "we'll just run Dataflow using the local runner".  In my opinion, that isn't a great idea.  One uses the localrunner for development and unit testing.  A local runner doesn't provide any form of horizontal scaling ... it literally runs on just one machine.

When one runs a pipeline job on distributed Dataflow, it creates as many workers as needed to sensibly distribute the job across many machines.  If the job then wishes to generate a result as file output ... the question then becomes "Where will that data be written?".   The answer can't be a local file relative to where the Dataflow job was run because, by definition, the job was run across multiple machines and there is no notion of one machine as the "output".  To solve this problem, data should be output to Google Cloud Storage which is a common storage area visible to all machines.  The related question posed by the OP describes a potential problem with writing data to GCS as opposed to local file (as found with local runner) but I believe *that* is the problem to be solved (i.e. how to write to centralized GCS storage correctly) rather than try and use a single VM.   Dataflow provides ZERO control over nature of the dataflow processing engines (workers).  They are logically ephemeral and are "just there" to process Dataflow work.

Comment: Your answer is amazing and so clear. Should I then ask the question regarding special characters with java and google storage as a separate question?

Comment: Yes indeed.  That would be my recommendation.  There are no limits to the questions you can ask and you should feel free and welcome to do so.  As a general rule, please try and look for existing (duplicate) questions before posting a new one.  When you do post new questions, please try and think about information a potential reader may want to know to best assist.  As a rule of thumb, I try and spend 3x more time writing a question than I might expect a reader to read it.  Well written and detailed/clear questions get the most attention.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Here is continue of this question) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170235/reading-from-bigquery-and-store-data-to-google-storage-special-character-issue