# Reading from BigQuery and store data to Google storage (Special Character issue)

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

Reference: [Can Google Data flow use existent VM and not temporary created ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167044/can-google-data-flow-use-existent-vm-and-not-temporary-created-ones/56169916#56169916)

Code is working, but the issue is that when it saves response from BigQuery to google storage all the Japanese characters are corrupted.

```
PCollectionTuple QVCollections = rows.apply("FilterEmptyRows", ParDo.of(new FilterEmptyRowDoFn("TransactionId", "TransactionDateTime"))).apply("CreateQVFiles",ParDo.of(new TransactionToQVFilesDoFnJP())
        .withOutputTags(BobShare.QVHeaders, TupleTagList.of(BobShare.QVEvents).and(BobShare.QVPayments)));

QVCollections.get(BobShare.QVEvents).apply("WriteQVEvents", TextIO.write().to(storagePath + CSV_OUTPUT_FOLDER + "events_" + timeSuffix).withoutSharding().withHeader(CSV_HEADER_EVENTS).withSuffix(".csv"));
QVCollections.get(BobShare.QVPayments).apply("WriteQVPayments", TextIO.write().to(storagePath + CSV_OUTPUT_FOLDER + "payments_" + timeSuffix).withoutSharding().withHeader(CSV_HEADER_PAYMENTS).withSuffix(".csv"));
QVCollections.get(BobShare.QVHeaders).apply("WriteQVHeaders", TextIO.write().to(storagePath + CSV_OUTPUT_FOLDER + "header_" + timeSuffix).withoutSharding().withHeader(CSV_HEADER_TRANSACTION).withSuffix(".csv"));
```

Based on what I have found, need to use `.withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())`

In addition, this is what have tried (but working only locally - DirectRunner)

```
private static void uploadBlob(String project, String bucket, String filename, String localfile) {
    String listFromCsv = readCsvFromLocalStorage(localfile);

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(project).build().getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucket, filename);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("application/json").setContentEncoding(UTF_8).build();
    try {
        storage.create(blobInfo, listFromCsv.getBytes(UTF_8));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private static String readCsvFromLocalStorage(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);

    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

        // read the first line from the text file
        String line = br.readLine();

        // loop until all lines are read
        while (line != null) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

private static void deleteLocalFile (String fileName)
{
    try {
        if (new File(fileName).delete()) {
            System.out.println(fileName + " deleted.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileName + " could not be deleted.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(fileName + " could not be deleted.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how data looks like (corrupted) :
[JAPANESE CHRACTERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZQ6P.png)

Any suggestions? Any .... (((

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is instrument the flow to find out at what point the data ie being transformed into the wrong format.  It might be at the start, middle or end and if we can narrow it down, that would help tremendously.

Comment: This is the point - `TextIO.write().to(storagePath + CSV_OUTPUT_FOLDER + "events_" + timeSuffix)`

Comment: To clarify, those are not actual japanese characters, but characters that have been wrongly encoded/decoded. Judging by the fact that latin characters, numbers, and punctuation marks are preserved, it means that somewhere there is a mismatch between input encoding and output encoding. For example if the input is something similar to ASCII 1-byte encoding, and the output is UTF8, then something like this can happen. Or if your file is UTF8 but your text editor doesn't know that and tries to display it as ASCII, for example.

Comment: I think there are still few pieces missing here: how is the text data produced, what is the input of the pipeline? Can you share the expected output that you get from DirectRunner that corresponds to the broken output from DataflowRunner, so that it is easier to determine the encoding issue (if it is encoding issue)?

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace

BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

by

BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

Comment: Can you explain the change? Looking at the `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, I see this: `public static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8")` so this change doesn't really change a bit.